# Embed twitter timeline in ol3 popup?

Tags: openlayers, twitter

I can embed a tweet in an ol3 popup using a simple iframe code stored in a geojson. The code uses a free service called twitframe.com:

```
<iframe border=0 frameborder=0 height=250 width=250 src=https://twitframe.com/show?url=https://twitter.com/exploreorg/status/1002995854159089664></iframe>
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Brian393/mr4n3w8z

However I would like to embed a full timeline, not just a single tweet from an individual's status. Instead it should be a hashtag, or even better, a moment (ie a curated collection of tweets), such as these:

https://twitter.com/hashtag/bearcam

https://twitter.com/i/moments/1006256948990312448

When I insert the URLs into the iframe above, they don't work. It seems that twitframe is designed to show only an individual tweet. Does anyone know how to embed a full timeline in an ol3 popup?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using the [official Twitter version](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/overview.html)?

Comment: Yes, because I haven't been able to get it work! If you or anyone could show how that is done on the fiddle it would really be a help.

Comment: Just to be clear, I want to see a full timeline in the popup, including pictures and videos. When I paste the official code from https://publish.twitter.com I just get a hyperlink. It may be necessary to add a function of some kind in the js, but I have been unable to find an example and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple [hack](https://support.ultranet.co.nz/hc/en-us/articles/215153823-Twitter-Embedding-in-a-page) that works for a curated collection (as well as a moment, a handle and some other things). It would be great to see a more flexible solution, particularly for displaying a hashtage timeline. But anyway, this might help someone.

Sign in to Twitter, then go to https://tweetdeck.twitter.com and create a collection of tweets. Click "share" and then "embed" in the editing tab. That will take you to publish.twitter.com, which will produce your script (choose "timeline" as display option). Using a text editor, place the generated code in an html file, like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/timelines/539487832448843776?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">National Park Tweets - Curated tweets by TwitterDev</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Save it as, for example, "tweet.html" and put that in a subfolder inside your map folder. Then put an iframe inside your geojson:

```
<iframe border='0' frameborder='0' height='600' width='350' src=MAPFOLDER/SUBFOLDER/tweet.html></iframe>
```

Adjust the iframe options as desired. I had minor formatting problems that were resolved by removing data-partner="tweetdeck" from the generated code stored in the html file.

If no one has a better solution I will accept this answer to my own question.